# Show that this integral operator is Hilbert-Schmidt

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, compact-operators

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space, $\mu$ and $\nu$ be $\sigma$-finite measures on $(E,\mathcal E)$, $q\in L^2(\mu\otimes\nu)$ and $$Qg:=\int\nu({\rm d}y)q(\;\cdot\;,y)g(y)\;\;\;\text{for }g\in L^2(\nu).$$

> Are we able to show that $Q$ is Hilbert-Schmidt from $L^2(\nu)$ to $L^2(\mu)$?

Let $(g_i)_{i\in I}$ be an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\nu)$. Then \begin{equation}\begin{split}\sum_{i\in I}\left\|Qg_i\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}^2&=\sum_{i\in I}\int\mu({\rm d}x)\left|\langle q(x,\cdot\;),g_i\rangle_{L^2(\nu)}\right|^2\\&\color{red}=\int\mu({\rm d}x)\sum_{i\in I}\left|\langle q(x,\cdot\;),g_i\rangle_{L^2(\nu)}\right|^2\\&=\int\mu({\rm d}x)\left\|q(x,\;\cdot\;)\right\|_{L^2(\nu)}^2=\left\|q\right\|_{L^2(\mu\otimes\nu)}^2<\infty.\end{split}\tag1\end{equation}

> The crucial equation is the red one. Which argument do we need?

*Remark*: Please note that I'm not assuming that $L^2(\mu)$ or $L^2(\nu)$ is separable. Is this a problem? Are we able to conclude that $Q$ is compact? Non-separability shouldn't be a problem, but I'm not sure whether I miss something crucial.

Comment: Beppo-Levi in case $L^2(\nu)$ is separable. Otherwise, the sum you begin with is undefined anyways.

Comment: @amsmath Why should it be undefined (in terms of unordered summation)?

Comment: Well, what would $\sum_{t\in\mathbb R}\|Qg_t\|_{L^2(\mu)}^2$ mean?

Comment: @amsmath See, for example, chapter 9.4 on page 86 here: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/3100supp.pdf.

Comment: Good point. The series should then converge to $\|q\|_{L^2}^2$ in this sense. But I am not sure whether this characterizes Hilbert-Schmidt operators. I guess yes, but don't know. EDIT: Wikipedia says it's true.

Comment: @amsmath I'd say the crucial point is that if a family $\mathcal X$ in a Banach space is summable, then $\{x\in\mathcal X:x\ne0\}$ is countable.

Comment: @amsmath We could apply Beppo-Levi if we could show that the sum on the left-hand side of the red equality is finite (since then it is a countable sum). Can we show this?

Comment: Look at Theorem 2.49 in the book you cited. For every finite $J\subset I$ you have $$\sum_{i\in J}\|Qg_i\|_\mu^2 = \int\sum_{i\in J}|\langle q(x,\cdot),g_i\rangle|^2\,d\mu(x) = \int\|P_Jq(x,\cdot)\|_\nu^2\,d\mu(x)\,\le\,\int\|q(x,\cdot)\|_\nu^2\,d\mu(x) = \|q\|_{\mu\otimes\nu}^2,$$where $P_J$ is the orthogonal projection onto the span of $\{g_i : i\in J\}$. So, by the theorem we have that $\|Qg_i\|_\mu^2$ is summable.

Comment: @amsmath Ah, sure. Seems like this yields a every easy proof of Beppo-Levi for series.